# Unable to access upvote/downvote input in a Django template

Tags: html, django, django-forms, django-templates

I am reading upvote/downvote from a Django template in the following manner:

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'vote' %}" class="vote_form">
{% csrf_token %} 
<input type="hidden" id="id_value" name="value" class="hidden_id" value="{{ btn1.value }}" />

<button type="input" name="btn1" value="1">upvote</button>
<button type="input" name="btn1" value="-1">downvote</button>

</form>
```

*Note: The object being voted on and the user_id creating the vote are also passed, using similar "hidden" input tags I've omitted copying above*

Look at my input tag. `value="{{ btn1.value }}"` is supposed to reference the relevant button that was clicked, passing on its value to the view which then processes the net votes.

But my syntax/logic isn't working. What do you suppose I'm doing wrong? Please advise.

Secondly, I'm uncomfortable assigning an integer value to upvote/downvote **in my template**. There's got to be a more secure way to do that. Any protips in this regard are more than welcome!

p.s. for reference, the following is happening in my view:

```
class VoteFormView(FormView):
    form_class = VoteForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        link = get_object_or_404(Link, pk=form.data["link"])
        user = self.request.user
        val= form.data["value"]
        prev_votes = Vote.objects.filter(voter=user, link=link)
        has_voted = (prev_votes.count() > 0)

        if not has_voted:
            Vote.objects.create(voter=user, link=link, value=val)
        else:
            prev_votes[0].delete()
        return redirect("home")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`type="input"` is not a valid button type. I'd get rid of the hidden input altogether, and change the buttons to inputs:

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'vote' %}" class="vote_form">
    {% csrf_token %} 

    <input type="submit" name="btn1" value="upvote">
    <input type="submit" name="btn1" value="downvote">
</form>
```

Then, in your view, you can use:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    btn1 = request.POST.get('btn1')

    if btn1 == 'upvote':
        # Do the upvote
    elif btn1 == 'downvote':
        # Do the downvote
```

Comment: Lemme give it a shot.

Comment: Works, though had to make a few medium-sized changes.